# Ошибка при сравнение 2 массивов: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined как

Tags: javascript

Даны 2 массива (пример ниже), при переборе выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Пробовал на разных длинах массива, иногда ошибка не выскакивает. Пробовал через forEach, итог тот же. Очень нужна помощь

```js
let arr1 = [["★ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Minimal Wear) ", " 20812.84"],
["StatTrak™ AWP | Graphite (Factory New) ", " 1975.00"],
["★ Moto Gloves | Polygon (Well-Worn) ", " 1552.00"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", " 22446.00"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Stained (Field-Tested) ", " 15789.35"],
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", " 17040.35"],
["★ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Field-Tested) ", " 15587.00"],
["★ Karambit | Black Laminate (Well-Worn) ", " 20478.00"],
["★ Ursus Knife | Doppler (Factory New) ", " 17314.84"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Night (Field-Tested) ", " 17296.84"],
["★ Karambit | Night (Minimal Wear) ", " 20635.84"],
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", " 17605.84"],
["★ Bayonet | Autotronic (Field-Tested) ", " 19704.35"],
["★ StatTrak™ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Field-Tested) ", " 16333.84"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Black Laminate (Minimal Wear) ", " 19136.00"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", "22331"],
["★ Sport Gloves | Hedge Maze (Battle-Scarred) ", " 16492.84"],
["StatTrak™ AWP | Graphite (Factory New) ", " 19875.00"],
["★ Moto Gloves | Polygon (Well-Worn) ", " 15525.00"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", " 22446.00"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Stained (Field-Tested) ", " 15789.35"]
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", 16989.35],
["★ Talon Knife | Case Hardened (Field-Tested) ", " 19497.35"], 
["★ Specialist Gloves | Emerald Web (Field-Tested) ", " 22140.35"],
["★ Karambit | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear) ", " 18173.00"],
["★ Bayonet | Doppler (Factory New) ", 20249]]

let arr2 = [["★ StatTrak™ Nomad Knife | Case Hardened (Field-Tested) ", " 20728.15"],
["StatTrak™ AWP | Graphite (Factory New) ", " 1975.00"],
["★ Moto Gloves | Polygon (Well-Worn) ", " 1552.00"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", " 22446.00"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Stained (Field-Tested) ", " 15789.35"],
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", " 17040.35"],
["★ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Field-Tested) ", " 15587.00"],
["★ Karambit | Black Laminate (Well-Worn) ", " 20478.00"],
["★ Ursus Knife | Doppler (Factory New) ", " 17314.84"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Night (Field-Tested) ", " 17296.84"],
["★ Karambit | Night (Minimal Wear) ", " 20635.84"],
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", " 17605.84"],
["★ Bayonet | Autotronic (Field-Tested) ", " 19704.35"],
["★ StatTrak™ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Field-Tested) ", " 16333.84"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Black Laminate (Minimal Wear) ", " 19136.00"],
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", 16647.35],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", 22331]]

let comparedArr = []


for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {

        if (arr1[i][0] === arr2[j][0]) {

            comparedArr.push(arr1[i][0] + ' : ' + 'Цена 1 - ' + arr1[i][1] + ', Цена2 - ' + arr2[j][1])

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Присмотритесь к задаче, автор не сравнивает два массива, а ищет все элементы, которые являются общими для двух массивов.

Comment: Отладчик для таких вещей существует.

Comment: Зачем вы отредактировали вопрос и дописали пропущенную запятую? Теперь ответ Вадима выглядит несколько странно ;)

Comment: Действительно) Верну все как было)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let arr1 = [["★ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Minimal Wear) ", " 20812.84"],
["StatTrak™ AWP | Graphite (Factory New) ", " 1975.00"],
["★ Moto Gloves | Polygon (Well-Worn) ", " 1552.00"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", " 22446.00"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Stained (Field-Tested) ", " 15789.35"],
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", " 17040.35"],
["★ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Field-Tested) ", " 15587.00"],
["★ Karambit | Black Laminate (Well-Worn) ", " 20478.00"],
["★ Ursus Knife | Doppler (Factory New) ", " 17314.84"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Night (Field-Tested) ", " 17296.84"],
["★ Karambit | Night (Minimal Wear) ", " 20635.84"],
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", " 17605.84"],
["★ Bayonet | Autotronic (Field-Tested) ", " 19704.35"],
["★ StatTrak™ Karambit | Ultraviolet (Field-Tested) ", " 16333.84"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Black Laminate (Minimal Wear) ", " 19136.00"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", "22331"],
["★ Sport Gloves | Hedge Maze (Battle-Scarred) ", " 16492.84"],
["StatTrak™ AWP | Graphite (Factory New) ", " 19875.00"],
["★ Moto Gloves | Polygon (Well-Worn) ", " 15525.00"],
["★ M9 Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear) ", " 22446.00"],
["★ Butterfly Knife | Stained (Field-Tested) ", " 15789.35"], // тут вы забыли запятую поставить
["★ Karambit | Freehand (Field-Tested) ", 16989.35],
["★ Talon Knife | Case Hardened (Field-Tested) ", " 19497.35"], 
["★ Specialist Gloves | Emerald Web (Field-Tested) ", " 22140.35"],
["★ Karambit | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear) ", " 18173.00"],
["★ Bayonet | Doppler (Factory New) ", 20249]]
```

Comment: Не досмотрел. Я правильно понимаю, циклы написаны верно, проблема была только в запятой?

Comment: Да, ошибка только в данной строке

Comment: Благодарю! Искал проблему очень долго)